# Text over an image in HTML not positioning correctly

Tags: html, css, position

I made my text over my image correctly, but the problem is I can't figure out how to make the text in its fixed place without moving when resizing the window.
Here is my code:

```css
img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Courier', monospace;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50vh;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.firstName {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 3em;
}

.secName {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 5em;
  color: rgb(200,0,0);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/ee/84/e5/ee84e597b90f4b6d827f4c73506e700d.jpg">
  <div class="firstName">
    <h1>Eren</h1>
  </div>
  
  <div class="secName">
    <h1>Yeager</h1>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

You see, when you resize the window the text pop out from the image box.

Comment: You should use html snippets for html/css code. Add it and I'll try to help

Comment: What do you mean, mate? I already inserted a code snippet there. @AlexBurla

Comment: oh it should be a bug. It showed up after reloading

Comment: No worries, mate.

Comment: "text in its fixed place" - where is it supposed to be, in relation to image? What if the window is too small, smaller than text? Does window have a min width?

Comment: So if I understood you well you change the size of `.container` and the text pops out from the image. Youy want the image to have static size not depending on `container` or you want the text to be linked to some image positions?

Comment: @TJ. I want the text to stay above Eren's head (the guy in the picture) when resizing. But whenever I resize the window the text goes away from its place not above his head directly, for example it goes right when I make the window smaller, and goes right when I make the window bigger. While here I want it to always stay above his head without moving at all whenever I resize so it'll look like the text is from the image itself. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I hope you got the idea. @AlexBurla

Comment: By resize do you mean zoom? It doesn't really move around when resizing with above snippet

Comment: It does move when you go full screen mode. Thanks to Alex he solved it for me. And thank you as well for taking the time to reply. @TJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your text linked to the specified position on the image you may set text positioning in percentage. Here is the way that can solve it:

```css
img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Courier', monospace;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50vh;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.firstName {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 40%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.secName {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 60%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  color: rgb(200,0,0);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/ee/84/e5/ee84e597b90f4b6d827f4c73506e700d.jpg">
  <div class="firstName">
    <h1>Eren</h1>
  </div>
  
  <div class="secName">
    <h1>Yeager</h1>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It helped and worked just like how I wanted it.

Comment: @LiquiKal glad to help :)